# How to have the same information in the "report.html" file from executing a test with keywords in a .resource file, in a .py file?

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

We start with two files with a keyword: The first is a .resource:

```
*** Keywords ***

Open page and click element
    open browser    http://www.amazon.com    chrome
    wait until element is visible    //*[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']    20
    input text    //*[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']    Ferrari 2345
    click element    //*[@id='nav-search-submit-text']
```

And the second a .py:

```
@keyword("Open page and click element")
def open_page_and_click_element(self):
    osw.open_browser("http://www.amazon.com", "chrome")
    osw.wait_until_element_is_visible("//*[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']", 20)
    osw.input_text("//*[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']", "Ferrari 2345")
    osw.click_element("//*[@id='nav-search-submit-text']")
```

My problem is that when I run a certain test, which use the keyword defined in the .resource file, the log that it returns is as shown below:

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufzA8.png)

As we can see, the keywords we use appear, such as "click element", "wait until element is visible", etc.

However, if we place that same keyword in the .py file, and we execute the same test that uses that keyword, the result we obtain is the following:

[image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXYMI.png)

As we can see, the keywords that the keyword "open page and click element" uses do not appear, as when we execute that same keyword from a .resource file.

Is there a way that the report.html file has the same information if the keywords are executed from a .py file as from a .resource?

Comment: Don't post code as image. It makes the question unreadable, and hard to test it for those, who try to help you.  Post the code itself instead as code.

Comment: Read the following questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post